# Compiling a .TGZ - tutorial clarification using Compiling Things On Ubuntu The Easy Way

Tags: compiling

I am using a document entitled "Compiling things on Ubuntu the Easy Way". In step 2 "Getting the software you want", I have copied the downloaded .TGZ file, and extracted it (it created a separate folder entitled aic7xxx-2.6.  This folder contains 23 files (with extensions .h, .reg, .seq, .c, .h, .h-shipped, .c-shipped, and .reg) and a folder aicasm. Extraction was done by right click on the .tgz and selecting extract here. This is where I need clarification. The instruction says "If you already installed the packages listed on step 1 (the files are build-essentials and cvs subversion and checkinstall), you just need to change to your /usr/local/src directory and run the commands that are listed".  My problem is several. (1) There are no commands listed.  What was expected to be run? In step 3 "Resolving Dependencies, the extracted archive has no file named CONFIGURE. I did install apt-file but without knowing what to search for, I am stuck.  Can someone clue in in on what the next step is after extracting the .TGZ?  Oh yes, is build-essentials a library, no something to be run using the sudo command?

Comment: I believe this was last revised in 2004 and will be too old to builld in any recent Ubuntu version. Isn't this related to the driver *aic7xxx* that is already included in recent Ubuntu versions?

Comment: Hello.  aic7xxx is already in Ubuntu?? I have Server 15.xx and doing a search reveals no such file(s).  Is it in another version of Ubuntu?

Comment: In my fully updar\ted 15.10 install, it is at: `/lib/modules/4.2.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/scsi/aic7xxx/aic7xxx.ko`.

Comment: Chili555, thank you. Between you and cybea in the post below, I am now one step closer to completing this server. It turns out the my installation of Ubuntu already had the module loaded, I just did not know enough to realize it.

Comment: Glad it's solved. Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you used [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo)

Your question (1): look at extracted files - is there an executable or script? Some file with suffix `.sh`, `.py` or similar? Is there a file called `README`, `INSTALL` or similar which you can open with text editor to get instructions? Is there a file called `Makefile`? If you answer all questions with *NO* you might have to compile source *the hard way* using for example `gcc somefile.c -o somefile` and execute it using `./somefile`

`build-essential` installs basic packages (`libc6-dev | libc-dev, gcc, g++, make, dpkg-dev`) to compile c-programs and build `.deb` packages

Step 1 in tutorial asks you to install packages using

`sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall`

**BUT** I also assume you just want to load aic7xxx kernel module which comes with `linux-image-generic` (standard kernel) in ubuntu.

To check if module is already loaded:

`sudo lsmod | grep aic7xxx`

If not already loaded load with

`sudo modprobe aic7xxx`

Comment: Hello and thank you.  Yes, the link you have is the tutorial I am using. To answer you question, no- there no files with the extensions .sh or .py nor with the words readme in any of them.  No makefile either.  As was mentioned in an earlier post, I am trying to use a very old source code page from adaptec.com.  If you see the above reply, I did learn that Ubuntu already has a driver (module) file which I did not know.  It has the extension .ko which I believe means a loadable module. Already compiled and ready to load if I read right. There is also apparently a file ahc4.gz someplace.

Comment: Your source code has to be compatible with your kernel `uname -r` shows your running kernel version - `.ko` means kernel object. But if your kernel is properly installed you dont need to know where it is. `modprobe` knows where :)

Comment: Thank you...typing sudo lsmod lists the module as loaded!!! I wish we had connected sooner. I have spent hours trying to compile Adaptecs source code when you and chili555 pointed me in the direction I needed to go. It's terrible being a new user. Apparently Ubuntu sensed the installed card and installed the module from the very start, I just did not know enough to see that it was already a done deal. Thank you again.